# Parse arguments in string format into an array, but respect the nested commas in default params

Tags: ruby, regex

I am writing a ruby method that takes a string like this

```
"foo = { :foo => 'bar', :baz => \"{'foo' : 'bar', 'bar' : 'biff' }\" :bar => 'baz' }, bar, baz = \"('foo,bar,baz')\", &block"
```

and returns an array like this:

```
["foo = { :foo => 'bar', :baz => \"{'foo' : 'bar', 'bar' : 'biff' }\" :bar => 'baz' }", "bar", "baz = \"('foo,bar,baz')\"", "&block"]
```

However, so far I am unable to split the string correctly, my best effort still breaks the string on internal hashes e.g.

```
"foo = { :foo => 'bar', :baz => \"{'foo' : 'bar', 'bar' : 'biff' }\" :bar => 'baz' }, bar, "baz = \"('foo,bar,baz')\", &block".scan(/(?:[^,(]|\([^)]*\))+/)
```

Which produces:

```
["foo = { :foo => 'bar'", " :baz => \"{'foo' : 'bar'", " 'bar' : 'biff' }\" :bar => 'baz' }", " bar", " baz = \"('foo,bar,baz')\"", " &block"]
```

I think the regex i am using is close but i am not sure how to check for both parenthesis and curly brackets. Presently, the regex only searches for parentheses.

This is my current regex:

```
/(?:[^,(]|\([^)]*\))+/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

this does not suit you?

```
string.split(',')
```

Comment: Well, i think you rather escape those comments like \"('foo,bar,baz')\" and use split() instead of use complex regexp with can have unexpected behavior with unexpected input.